# How do I make subsequent restful http calls go to same node balanced by HAProxy?

Tags: rest, load-balancing, haproxy

I am used to using Linodes balancing services which has the option of all requests from the same source being routed to the same target machine - its called 'stickiness' in linodes solution (I havnt found much under haproxy stickiness).

How do I implement this scenario when using HAProxy?

The service i am using haproxy with is a standard http restful api that will be called by mobile clients.

I have found that i can use the source ip to make sure all requests from  same ip goto same server, but this wont work if mobile client switches between 3g and wifi.

Comment: There should be a lot on "Sticky Session" for HAProxy: http://blog.haproxy.com/2012/03/29/load-balancing-affinity-persistence-sticky-sessions-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: thanks @Davin for the link, looks like adding a cookie via haproxy will do it.

Comment: no probs.  There might be an ip affinity setting that would help as well, if you don't want to terminate ssl in HAProxy.

Comment: I will be adding one SSL certificate to the haproxy - is that what you mean terminating SSL at haproxy?

Comment: Yes.  if you are terminating at haproxy (by adding a cert), then cookies seem like a good option.